# How to make eclipse work with C(not c++) code in android NDK?

Tags: c, eclipse, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

I have very big issues with eclipse and NDK.
It completely do not recognize C code.

> (*java_vm)->DetachCurrentThread (java_vm);

Throws semantic error by CDT, while it sees

```
java_vm->DetachCurrentThread ();
```

as a valid one (while it isn't for C).
File has a .c extension compiles well, despite that CDT just doesn't work on it. To add insult to injury it properly founds the method by ctrl+clicking on function.

Also I do not know if it is related, but it just not recognize anything from GLIB.
It includes `#include <glib/glib.h>` but does not traverse anymore: for example it does not recognize `gboolean` datatype from . Same with other includes (In some cases it works: `#include <gst/gst.h>` include `gst/gstelement.h` struct type `GstElement` is seen as valid and recognized). However Index->find unresolved includes helped to find few missing paths, so it understands what include are here. Also auto-complete shows proper headers, but it cant find anything from them. Some built-in libraries like `<android/log>` has similar issues.

Everything compiles well just CDT cannot traverse code. I am thinking about finding something to switch away from eclipse if these issues remain for NDK development, but couldn't find anything or solve any of problems.

I am using latest android development bundle with ADT 22, Eclipse 4.3.1, CDT 8.2.1.

How to configure Eclipse to properly recognize headers?

Comment: [HERE](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_o_proj_files.htm) you have the eclipse documentation about how use C project.

Comment: Conversion to c/c++ nature does not work (not needed??? project is not candidate for adding nature) for r9 NDK. Also most of this applies to C/C++ in general not Android NDK.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's the same, still open issue with ADT/NDK, almost 5 years in running. There are ugly workarounds (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788 for more info), like reconfiguring the toolchain or just trying to get by with C++ by changing the suffix to .cpp but no full fix.